# php - empty() function for cookies is not working

Tags: php, cookies

I would like to show a popup message when users are coming for the first time on my website. The problem is that the popup is always coming back when I refresh the page. I did it this way:

If a user comes on the website, I have an PHP function that checks if he has a cookie named `"first_time"` set.

```
<?php if (empty($_COOKIE["first_time"])) {
 echo 'yes';
} else {
 echo 'no';
}
```

As you can imagine, there is always `'yes'` message.

When I go to `Applications -> Cookies` on Chrome I find the cookie `"first_time"` with value `"no"`. So I understand that the cookie `"first_time"` is not empty and the echo message should be `"no"`.

I tried to remove the cache also but doesn't seem to work.

var_dump($_COOKIE) show me this:

```
array(10) { ["first_time"]=> string(2) "no"...
```

The cookie is set this way when a user clicks to close the popup:

```
function remove_popup(){
  document.cookie = 'first_time=no; expires=Sun, 28 Feb 2030 00:00:00 UTC';
}
```

Comment: First of all, check what you actually get inside your script, `var_dump($_COOKIE);` And show where / when you are setting it, and with what parameters

Comment: Where are you setting the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something wrong with the code which you do not show to us.
I made this simple test `.php` file

```php
<HTML>
 <BODY>
<?php if (empty($_COOKIE["first_time"])) {
 echo 'first time';
} else {
 echo 'hello again';
}
?>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    document.cookie = 'first_time=no; expires=Sun, 28 Feb 2030 00:00:00 UTC';
  </SCRIPT>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I access it for the first time I see `first time` but after I refresh the page I see `hello again`

Check carefully your code.

Answer (score 1):

The empty function checks if the variable is null, empty or undefined. In your case, you say that there is in fact a cookie set with that name and the value "no". So your cookie is in fact not empty, because it contains a string that has two characters: "n" and "o".

Comment: Yes so because it's not empty the php condition should echo 'no' if I'm right

Comment: `isset()` a better option for this.

Comment: isset() send me always false so that's the same issue.